# how to scroll up layout when clicking on edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my layout with soft input mode and without soft input mode.

But main problem is when i click next from second last edit text, i want to show those two buttons and last edit text with soft input mode. Please help

my xml file is as follows

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/scroll_bg" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="521dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <com.deemtech.widgets.MenuLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/customer_details"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNameCustomerDetails"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="NAME"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_create_account1x"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmailCustomerDetails"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="EMAIL ADDRESS"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editEmailCustomerDetails"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="CONTACT NUMBER"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <!--
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editAdditionalInfo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/message_additional_box1x"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="ADDITIONAL INFO"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editAdditionalInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="ADDITIONAL INFO"
            android:background="@drawable/message_additional_box1x"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:lines="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:width="150dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBackCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="448dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSubmitCustomerDetails"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmitCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editNameCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="448dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_submit"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: you need to provide the current xml to check. Basically you need to redesign your layout.

Comment: i added my xml file here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you cant simply "adjustResize" the window. Also as you only want to show the buttons when the last edit text is clicked.

So you can try this approach, not truly suggested but will work for your scenario:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainf);


    findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalInfo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(sampleMediaPlayer.this, "text", 700).show();
            findViewById(R.id.btnBackCustomerDetails).requestFocusFromTouch();
            findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalInfo).requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot sir.. thank u very much. u dont knw how much it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453561/layout-on-keyboard-in-android)

 or 
try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity in `manifest` file.

Comment: this in not workin in my case. it still hides my buttons.. :(

Comment: ok. than change layout design. or if it's possible for you than try this android:layout_height="match_parent" to RelativeLayout and give it a fix id also. maybe it's work for you.

Comment: @MohitRaval Please update or remove the mentioned link. It says 404 for the given link in your answer

Answer (score 0):

with the help of nimish's answer i finally got wat i wanted

```
    editPhoneCustomerDetails.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                findViewById(R.id.btnBackCustomerDetails).requestFocusFromTouch();
                findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalInfo).requestFocusFromTouch();
                //((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

                //findViewById(R.id.editPhoneCutomerDetails).requestFocusFromTouch();

               // findViewById(R.id.btnBackCustomerDetails).requestFocusFromTouch(); 
            }
    return false;
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalInfo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //findViewById(R.id.btnBackCustomerDetails).setFocusable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.btnBackCustomerDetails).requestFocusFromTouch();
            findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalInfo).requestFocusFromTouch();
        }

    });
```